# Laravel Livewre: on select change, pass the selected value into the method in wire:change

Tags: laravel-livewire

i have this select tag on Livewire component:

```html
<select 
    class="form-select deliveryGuySelect" 
    id="order-{{THIS_NEED_TO_BE_$dg->id}}" 
    wire:change="assignOrder({{$order->id}})"
>
    @foreach($deliveryGuys as $dg)
       <option value="{{$dg->id}}" wire:key="{{$dg->id}}">{{$dg->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And I need, on `assignOrder()` action from select tag, to send the option value as parameter `$dg->id`.

How can I do that?

Comment: i appreciate a comment with your negative vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Livewire and Alpine together expose the `$event` magic action-object, which can target the option that was selected, and the value it has, by using `$event.target.value`

```html
<select wire:change="setSomeProperty($event.target.value)">
    <!-- Options here -->
</select>
```

- https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions#magic-actions

Comment: ... and you Sir, deserve a cookie!